# Auto Update SVN after Commit and Export it to zip

Tags: linux, git, svn, google-code

Me and my friends are developing android Custom ROMS, the problem is we immediately update when there is something need to update. i use google code trunk to upload our custom roms for now and i need to zip it and upload it, is there is a way for a better proccess that our server automatically svn update when i commit, and export it to zip automatically too? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand. However, I think you might find [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), a build server, to be helpful.

With Jenkins, you can have it build on command, at specific times, or when the source code repository itself was changed. You can also *archive* your ZIP file in a Jenkins build webpage itself.

How do you do your builds now? Do you use [Ant](http://ant.apache.org)? If you use Ant, you can have Ant to create the Zipfiles themselves, and store them in Jenkins. You could even have Jenkins automatically load your built custom ROM directly to Google Code.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, thank you, that jenkins what i was looking for. i use maven over Ant.